# separating point from convex hull with hyperplane, when point is in another convex set

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, compactness

If I have a point in a compact convex set containing a compact set $A$ but the point is not in the convex hull of $A$, then how could I prove that the point could be seperated from the compact set $A$ with a hyperplane?

Comment: [Yes.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hahn–Banach_theorem#Hahn.E2.80.93Banach_separation_theorem)

Comment: I've looked at the seperation theorems and nothing directly applies to this case. perhaps I could construct two convex sets that are disjoint and apply a well know seperation theorem there?  but how can I prove that the hyper plane wont intersect the compact set $A$

Comment: On the contrary, it implies your question directly. You have $\{x\}$, which is compact and convex, and the convex hull $\operatorname{conv}(A)$, which is compact and convex. These are disjoint by assumption.